# how to show that $r ≤\frac{n}{2}$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : R^n → R^n$ be a linear transformation such that $ T^
2 = 0$. If $r$
denotes the rank of $T $(that is,$ r = dim(Image(T)))$, then show that
$r ≤\frac{n}{2}$

i know that by Rank-nuliity theorem The dimension of $T$   will be $n$ as$ T^2=0$ mean  T  is a nilpotent ..so dimension of T will be  $n-2$.

But here im confused  how  dimension of $ r = dim(Image(T)))$ will be$ ≤\frac{n}{2}$.

Any Hints or solutions  will be appreciated

thank in  advance for helping me
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $T^2=0$ we get $Im(T) \subseteq ker(T)$, hence $\dim ker(T) \ge r$.

It follows that:

$n= r+ \dim ker(T) \ge 2r$.

Comment: thanks a lots @fred

Answer (score 0):

Since $T^2=$ it follows $im(T)\subset \ker(T)$. Now 
$$
n = \dim(im T) + \dim (\ker T) = rank(T) + \dim(\ker T) \le 2 \dim(\ker T)
$$
Hence
$$
\dim(\ker T) \ge n/2
$$
and
$$
\dim(im T) = rank(T) \le n/2
$$.

Comment: thanks a lots @daw